# CSS not centering

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and css.

```css
  .divOuter {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.divInner1,
.divInner2,
.divInner3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://i.cubeupload.com/jmdKlW.png"></img>
</div>
<div id="title">
  <h3>Who's watching</h3>
</div>
<div class="divOuter">
  <div class="divInner1">First DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner2">Second DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner3">Third DIV</div>
</div>
```

I used the outer div to try and center everything inside. but i get the following image:
[image]

The squares in the middle are not centered. A working example is on xat.me/madses1996

I would like the squares next to eachtother.

Comment: Side note, there is no `</img>`

Comment: Oopsie, will fix that @j08691

Comment: _"The squares in the middle are not centered"_ - why would they be, you're floating them - "floating" and "centering" are opposite concepts, you can't have both at the same time. Use inline-block instead ... or go flexbox.

Comment: Is floating absolutely necessary?

Comment: flex is the way to go - check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use **flex** on **outer**

```
.divOuter {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.divInner1,
.divInner2,
.divInner3 {
  flex: 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `.divOuter` is correctly centered, but the problem is that you're apply a fixed width of `150px` to your three inner elements. Swapping this to a percentage-based width of `100%` correctly centers the elements:

```css
.divOuter {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.divInner1,
.divInner2,
.divInner3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://i.cubeupload.com/jmdKlW.png" />
</div>
<div id="title">
  <h3>Who's watching</h3>
</div>
<div class="divOuter">
  <div class="divInner1">First DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner2">Second DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner3">Third DIV</div>
</div>
```

If you want to make use of a fixed width, you can do so by definining it on `.divOuter`:

```css
.divOuter {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.divInner1,
.divInner2,
.divInner3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://i.cubeupload.com/jmdKlW.png" />
</div>
<div id="title">
  <h3>Who's watching</h3>
</div>
<div class="divOuter">
  <div class="divInner1">First DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner2">Second DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner3">Third DIV</div>
</div>
```

Also note that the **[`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)** tag is **[self-closing](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)**; there is no `</img>` tag.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Nice and centered but they are underneath now i wanted them next to eachother

Comment: @Kevin.a You may want to clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome's Inspect, I got the results I think you are looking for with these updates to the .divInner1, 2 & 3 CSS classes.

1. remove: "float: left;"
2. add: "display: inline-block;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
  

    body{
  
  background: black;
}

#title h3{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.divOuter {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .divInner1,
    .divInner2,
    .divInner3 {
          border: 1px solid white;
        
          width: 150px;
          height: 150px;
          margin-left: 3px;
          margin-right: 3px;
          margin-top: 50px;
          text-align: center;
          display: inline-block;
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://i.cubeupload.com/jmdKlW.png"></img>
</div>
<div id="title">
  <h3>Who's watching</h3>
</div>
<div class="divOuter">
  <div class="divInner1">First DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner2">Second DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner3">Third DIV</div>
</div>
```

```css
.divOuter {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.divInner1,
.divInner2,
.divInner3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://i.cubeupload.com/jmdKlW.png" />
</div>
<div id="title">
  <h3>Who's watching</h3>
</div>
<div class="divOuter">
  <div class="divInner1">First DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner2">Second DIV</div>
  <div class="divInner3">Third DIV</div>
</div>
```